# Prevent Shutter Moving Worskspace

Tags: shutter

I mapped the `shutter --active` command to alt-print screen for taking screenshots of my active window. Unfortunately, if Shutter is already open in another workspace instead of minimized, then Shutter will not take the screenshot until after it has started moving me to the workspace that the shutter window is open in. The only way to workaround this is to make sure shutter is minimized before trying to take the screenshot. This will result in shutter opening in your current workspace which is annoying for those of us who like to keep our workspaces organized.

**Is there a way to have shutter take the screenshot without changing my view to the workspace shutter is currently open within?** I have already tried disabling "auto hide main window..." and "present main window after taking a screenshot" inside behavior settings.

[Youtube video of issue.](http://youtu.be/oWyKTR9G_mE)

Comment: No matter what settings I choose, it doesn't show the behaviour you mention. Shutter either moves *the shutter window* to the current viewport or shows the snapshot on its own viewport, but the snapshot is always correct. Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Im usuing ubuntu 14.04 64bit. Shutter -v shows: 0.90.1 Rev.1259

Comment: Added a video to help demonstrate.

Comment: Why are you using `shutter` not `gnome-screenshot`? Oh, and you can't put `iframes` in this site.

Comment: @Tim because shutter has a lot of features that I take advantage of.

Comment: Could you specify them? There may be a command I can give that will do similar things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want or need to use Shutter, you can simply use the workaround below:

You can automatically have Shutter gracefully closed (not killed) before taking a screenshot, thus preventing the move to another viewport. Since it is *gracefully* closed, there is no risk of losing images; they are saved automatically.
After the screenshot, Shutter will be running so you will not notice the difference.

To make it work you have to map the command below to the key combination, instead of running `shutter --active` directly from the key combination:

```
kill -s TERM $( pgrep shutter );shutter --active
```

Comment: That works when one types it into the CLI, but I am unable to get it to work with setting keyboard shortcuts with gsettings through the CLI. E.g. http://programster.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/cli-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: @Programster I don't see why that wouldn't work, there is probably some kind of a clash. To test, you can add the shortcut via System Settings to an available key combination. If that works (I have it working here) there must be some kind of a clash. The script you mention should not be doing anything different than the manual way.

Comment: Silly mistake of mine, when executing the script, $( pgrep shutter ) was getting evaluated immediately so in settings it was looking something like so: `kill -s TERM 10778; shutter --select`

Comment: Perfect I am glad it works :)